# Instant update of basic cloudbees java application run locally

Tags: java, web-applications, cloudbees

Trying to run basic java application (backbone.js and jax-rs) I was pleasantly surprised that modifying js or html file in src/main does not require application rebuild. Just refreshing it in browser is enough to update the application.

However changing java file, I can't find how to make application be updated locally.

Using Eclipse it's automatically compiled into target/classes, however applicaiton is not updated in browser. I can't find any bees command to cause update. I don't see compile command also.

Killing running tomcat and 'bees run' makes the trick, but the question is, if instant update is possible in case of basic java web application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with a normal Java app. One option would be to use Playframework has this auto-reloading stuff built in, and is supported well on CloudBees. http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework

Comment: Thank you, but I don't like it currently :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like JavaRebel or Javeleon if you wish to reload Java classes in a running application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I expected some 'bees' command from cloudbees sdk to redeploy locally. Well it is not instant update then, sorry for confusion.